# Cannot display custom icons from KML file

Tags: javascript, google-api, icons, kml

My KML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Style id="cafeIcon">
    <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
            <href>http://beta-gmapsapi.esy.es/images/markers/cafe.png</href>
        </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
    <name>Test marker</name>
    <description>Description for test marker</description>
    <styleUrl>#cafeIcon</styleUrl>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>30.46633243560791,50.44826825956681,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Here I connect my KML-file

```
function loadKmlLayer(map) {
        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://beta-gmapsapi.esy.es/kml/test.kml',
            suppressInfoWindows: false,
            preserveViewport: true,
            map: map
        });
    }
```

But after saving I see standart google marker..
[Everything works,  but icon doesn't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKU8Z.jpg)

Maybe here is some problems with syntax?

Comment: The [posted KML works in KmlLayer for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160429_iconStyle.kml), maybe there is an old version of your KML file stuck in one of Google's caches (sometimes it takes an hour or two to update, if you don't change the URL).

Comment: Do you know ways to fix this problem? Because now I am seeing standart marker...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the KML that is doing that?  The snippet you posted works for me (as I said), does [my link](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160429_iconStyle.kml) not show you what you expect (that is just displaying the KML you posted in your question)?

Comment: KML is here: http://beta-gmapsapi.esy.es/kml/test.kml Yes, your link works, I saw..

Comment: [Your KML works for me as well](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://beta-gmapsapi.esy.es/kml/test.kml)

Comment: Yes, but it displays standart marker, not custom. That is the main problem..

Comment: Not for me, it displays the yellow coffee cup. Maybe moving the KML to a different server.

Comment: Can it be a problem with links? First time you check your own kml, it worked. But your second answer doesn't work (http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://beta-gmapsapi.esy.es/kml/test.kml). I see blue marker!

Comment: I think, that is a problem with server..

Comment: I think that your server (or at least http://beta-gmapsapi.esy.es) is not returning the icon image quickly enough for Google's KML renderer.  If that takes too long, it replaces it with the default icon).  Try using an icon from one of google's servers. (http://kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html).  Might also be a geographic dependency, how long the latency is from the ["server"](http://beta-gmapsapi.esy.es) to the google maps machine that is doing the rendering, might be different for me vs. you.

Comment: Possibly related to: [Issue 9102: Bug: custom icons replaced by blue default icon on an API map](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9102)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks geocodezip

It was a problem with server. It took long time to show a result..